# Getting error from TFS 2015 trying to restore packages from a private feed

Tags: tfs, nuget, tfs-2015, nuget-package-restore

We have an on-premise **TFS 2015** build. We've recently added a reference to a 3rd party package. I have added a `nuget restore` build step to our build pipeline before the `MSBUILD` step to restore the package.

[image]

Here's the `nuget restore` build task

[image]

Here's the `MSBUILD` step

[image]

The error message I'm getting is this.

```
Failed to retrieve information about 'myPrivatePackage' from remote source 'https://nuget.myPrivatePackage.com/nuget/FindPackagesById()?id='myPrivatePackage'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.
```

Here's the build output log.

[image]

**UPDATE**

Here's the detailed TFS build log output from the nuget restore step.

```
Task "RestoreTask"
         (in) RestoreGraphItems Count '19'
         (in) RestoreDisableParallel 'False'
         (in) RestoreNoCache 'True'
         (in) RestoreIgnoreFailedSources 'False'
         (in) RestoreRecursive 'True'
         (in) RestoreForce 'False'
         (in) HideWarningsAndErrors 'False'
         (in) RestoreForceEvaluate 'False'
         Running restore with 4 concurrent jobs.
         Reading project file E:\TfsData\Build\_work\4\s\OscarWeb\OscarWeb.csproj.
         Reading project file E:\TfsData\Build\_work\4\s\OscarWeb\OscarWeb.csproj.
         Persisting no-op dg to E:\TfsData\Build\_work\4\s\OscarWeb\obj\OscarWeb.csproj.nuget.dgspec.json
         Restoring packages for E:\TfsData\Build\_work\4\s\OscarWeb\OscarWeb.csproj...
         Restoring packages for E:\TfsData\Build\_work\4\s\OscarWeb\OscarWeb.csproj...
         Restoring packages for .NETCoreApp,Version=v2.2...
         Restoring packages for .NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1...
           GET https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='BuildBundlerMinifier'&semVerLevel=2.0.0
           GET https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools'&semVerLevel=2.0.0
         Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 'https://nuget.telerik.com/nuget/FindPackagesById()?id='BuildBundlerMinifier'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
         The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.
```

Any ideas what is causing the error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to get this working by using the `dotnet restore` command instead of `nuget restore`.

```
dotnet restore "MyProject.csproj"  --configfile "nuget.config" --verbosity detailed --packages "rootfolder\packages" --no-cache
```

My 3rd party packages are now being restored as part of the build pipeline correctly.

Answer (score 1):

According to your screenshot. One issue I notice is that the MSBuild task is doing a restore at all. It shouldn't. Let the Nuget task do the NuGet restore.

Suggest go to Advanced options for the build task and uncheck "Restore NuGet Packages" or if there is some other way you are invoking NuGet restore during the build turn that off.

If this is not do the trick, also set variable `system.debug=true` to [Enable Verbose Debug Mode for TFS Build vNext](https://www.benday.com/2016/09/19/enable-verbose-debug-mode-for-tfs-build-vnext/). Which may provide more detail info for troubleshooting.

Comment: When I try that I get the following error message:

"Assets file 'MyProject\obj\project.assets.json' not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file."

Comment: Hi  DomBurf, according to your error message, seems your Nuget Install task didn't restore the package at all. You could check the logs of Nuget Install task if your build service account access that private feed and download files. If not, this maybe the root cause. Then you could try to narrow down , if your build service account have enough permission/access to the private feed. Also check if network block your build agent to private feed url to download packages.

Comment: I have disabled the "restore" on the build step but still getting exactly the same error message.

Comment: Hi @DomBurf According to your updated logs  `Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 'https://nuget.telerik.com/nuget/FindPackagesById()?id='BuildBundlerMinifier'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.`  Since you are trying to get source from a 3rd-party site `https://nuget.telerik.com`. Not sure what's your nuget.config looks like. But I guess  `..telerik.com` should need some extra authentication. This may cause some issue. Suggest you could  use Remote Desktop to connect to the build server and open the project in Visual Studio there, check if it restores the packages and builds fine.

Comment: I'ver got it working by using "dotnet restore" instead of "nuget restore"

Comment: @DomBurf Glad to hear this, you could share your solution here as an answer, then mark your reply, which will also helps others in the community.